# How can I make my cards as binary groups on PC view

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page with using cards, It seems perfectly ok on phone, but when I check it on PC The cards seems just in the bottom. How can I make them look as binary groups for PC view?

It looks like this:

[image: PC view of my cards]

I want to make them look like this.

[image: PC view of the cards which i wanna do]

````html
<div align="center" class="justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
<div class="card-deck">
<div class="card" style="width:330px">
<center><h2 style="color:LightBlue;">CPX</h2>
<div class="card-body">  ```
````

Comment: [This](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) should help (assuming BS 4). Or [This](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) for BS 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you provided your `CSS` and complete `Html` . It will be easy to answer for community . Well you can try this code :

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.card-deck{           /*Assuming this class as parent of all your cards*/
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2.5rem;  /*According to need*/
}

.card{
  width: 45%;       /*According to need , such that no vertical scroll apear*/
  height: 30%;      /*According to need*/
  padding: 20px;   /*According to need*/
}
```